# TeeChart for .NET 2016 and TeeChart for .NET 2006

Tags: .net, for-loop, teechart

Our customer has purchased the TeeChart for .NET 2016 this Nov.
And now they got the questions below:

1. They found out that the chart is more unclear than the TeeChart 2006.

2016

[image: 2016]

2006

[image: 2006]

2. Is it possible to let the code is the same as TeeChart 2006 for calling Chart Editor Mode?

(I cannot past the code here and don't know how to attache file here, if you need the code, please kindly let me know)

Comment: Hello Tania, 

You can send your project to "info at steema dot com" referencing this question at stackoverflow. If that's a test application, you can also use some online storage giving public access to it. Remember isn’t necessary you attached the Teechart.dll in the project. 

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello Tania, I have sent you an email with update information about the problems you're experiencing.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> 1. They found out that the chart is more unclear than the TeeChart 2006.

Unfortunately, I haven't seen differences between TeeChart 2016 and TeeChart 2006 adapting the codes because the results, are shown similar in both versions.  You can see below the examples:

**TeeChartForNet V2016**

```
 public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                InitializeChart();
            }
            private void InitializeChart()
            {
                Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Points point1 = new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Points(tChart1.Chart);
                this.Text = tChart1.ProductVersion;
                tChart1.Aspect.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.Default;

                tChart1.Walls.Visible = false;
                tChart1.Aspect.View3D = false;
                tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Grid.Visible = true;
                tChart1.Axes.Left.Grid.Visible = true;
                tChart1.Axes.Left.AxisPen.Visible = true;
                tChart1.Axes.Left.Grid.Style = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dash;

                point1.FillSampleValues(100);
                point1.Color = Color.Blue;
                point1.Pointer.Pen.Color = Color.Black;
            }
```

**TeeChartForNet V2006**

```
public Form1(){

            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeChart();
        }
        private void InitializeChart()
        {
            Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Points point1 = new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Points(tChart1.Chart);
            tChart1.Panel.Gradient.Visible = false;
            tChart1.Panel.Color = Color.White;
            tChart1.Walls.Visible = false;
            this.Text = tChart1.ProductVersion;
            tChart1.Aspect.View3D = false;
            point1.FillSampleValues(100);
            point1.Color = Color.Blue;
            point1.Pointer.Pen.Color = Color.Black;
        }
```

Could you please, check if the above code TeeChartForNet 2016 works in you end?

> 2. Is it possible to let the code is the same as TeeChart 2006 for calling Chart Editor Mode?

The Chart Editor can show using same code lines, in TeeChart 2016 than TeeChart 2006. I have added below different lines code that show what you need do:

**Show Chart editor without Editor Component**

```
 tChart1.ShowEditor();
```

**Show  Chart Editor with Editor Component**

```
 ed1.ShowModal();
```